# Trying to put a flash project for i-pad but on itunes it comes up as an i-phone app

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash

I am making an i-pad app in flash as3.  I have all the certificates and am able to upload it to i-tunes, however it is coming up under i-phone apps not i-pad apps and when i download it onto my i-pad it is i-phone size.  I have been told that the solution to this should sit in the xml document but even after a lot of searching the web I cannot find how to edit the doc.  Here is the entire xml doc if anyone has any ideas

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/18.0">

<id>za.co.brandfoundry</id>
<versionNumber>0.1</versionNumber>
<supportedProfiles>mobileDevice</supportedProfiles>
<filename>Whiskeyfori-pad</filename>

<name>Whiskey for i-pad</name>
<description></description>
<copyright></copyright>

<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[

        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
          <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"/>
        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
<iPhone> 
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[ 

        <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key> 
        <string>UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque</string> 
        <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key> 
        <string>NO</string>
        <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>  
        <true/>
        <key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
        <true/>

        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <!-- iPhone support -->
            <string>1</string> 
            <!-- iPad support -->
            <!--<string>2</string>-->
        </array>

    ]]></InfoAdditions> 
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone> 

<initialWindow>
    <title>Whiskey for i-pad</title>
    <content>Whiskeyfori-pad.swf</content>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <!--<autoOrients>false</autoOrients>-->
    <!--<aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>-->
    <renderMode>direct</renderMode>
    <!--<depthAndStencil>true</depthAndStencil>--> <!-- required for 3D -->
</initialWindow>

<icon>
    <image48x48>icons/icon_48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>icons/icon_57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>icons/icon_72.png</image72x72>
    <image76x76>icons/icon_76.png</image76x76>
    <image96x96>icons/icon_96.png</image96x96>
    <image114x114>icons/icon_114.png</image114x114>
    <image120x120>icons/icon_120.png</image120x120>
    <image144x144>icons/icon_144.png</image144x144>
    <image152x152>icons/icon_152.png</image152x152>
    <!--<image512x512>icons/icon_512.png</image512x512>-->
</icon>

<!-- 
AIR options:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/File_formats_1.html#1043413

AIR mobile options:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html

iOS icons guidelines:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Android manifest documentation:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html
-->
```

Comment: [Read this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f7e64a7f12cd2dd1867-8000.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac-3cb3c27712e2339d6cd-8000) and you should really be more careful when reading, in the xml you posted you even have comments that say "iPhone support" and "ipad support". Right now, only iPhone is enabled, uncomment the `<string>2</string>` beneath `<key>UIDeviceFamily</key>`

Comment: Thanks so much.  I thought the problem was there but didnt realise it was commented out, it makes it obvious in stack overflow but in my flash it doesnt change colour. 

Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncomment `<!--<string>2</string>-->` in your xml manifest file. I can see this has been answered in the comments but in your question you state it's an iPad app. To restrict your app to only be available on iPad's you need to comment out the line `<string>1</string>`.

**EDIT:** Although it's not part of an answer to your question keep in mind that this line: `<name>Whiskey for i-pad</name>` is how your app name will look on your device. This name does not have to be unique so you could use Whiskey. :)